# Edit RGB pixel data using CImg - Visual C++ 2008

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2008, graphics, cimg

Using CImg:  I read [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/cimg/discussion/334630/thread/6cb630af) that you can change an individual pixel's RGB data like this:

```
CImg<float> img("filename.jpg");
// Change the (100,200) pixel to Red.
img(100,200,0,0) = 255; //R
img(100,200,0,1) = 0; //G
img(100,200,0,2) = 0; //B
```

but `img(100, 200, 0, 0)` returns the type `unsigned char *`, which is obviously not a variable as the above snippet implies.  When I run the above code, I get "error C2106: '=' : left operand must be l-value" in my build output.

A potential solution would be to use a different version of the `CImg` constructor, which takes raw pixel data as its first parameter, but I can't find any information on how to format the data before running it through the constructor - the first parameter is describes as a template in line 9671 of [CImg.h](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cimg/files/CImg-1.5.6_beta.zip/download).

Any help would be greatly appreciated; I've been at this for a while.

Comment: CImg.draw_point() *facepalm*

Answer (score 1):

The expression `img(100,200,0,0)` is not a `unsigned char*` but a `unsigned char&` which makes a huge difference. Of course you can write `img(100,200,0,0) = value` without any problems (except if your `img` variable is `const`), I use it all the time.
Note also that the third argument can be omitted in your case, as it is always `0`, so you can write `img(x,y,0)=255; img(x,y,1)=1; img(x,y,2)=1;`.

Look at the examples provided in the CImg package, you will see that many code uses the `CImg<T>::operator()`like this. Hopefully !

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `draw_point`.

From the reference manual:

> CImg& draw_point (
>   const int x0,
>   const int y0,
>   const int z0,
>   const tc ∗const color,
>   const float opacity = 1 )